# Removing COM event handlers automatically in C#

Tags: c#, events, com, finalizer

I have a standalone .exe COM server and a trivial C# test program that launches an instance of the server and closes it immediately afterwards. Works like a charm. However, if I close the C# program itself I get an exception during the finalizer run because it is trying to unregister/unadvise COM event sinks from the no longer running COM server.

The exception is
"A first chance exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

And the callstack:
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsSink.Unadvise() + 0x20 bytes   mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsSink.RemoveAll(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsSink sinks) + 0x11 bytes
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComEventsInfo.Finalize() + 0x18 bytes

I can fix this error by manually removing the COM event handlers before shutting down the server. I.e. myComServer.OnFunkyEvent -= OnFunkyEventHandler; However, I find this inelegant, error prone and tedious. So the question is, can I somehow trigger the RemoveAll() call for my COM events manually so it won't run in the finalizer?